# Issues with request_irq on 4.9.30-bone4 kernel on Beaglebone Green

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I have an issue installing an interrupt handler in a hardware driver, in this specific case for the am3358 e-capture unit eCAP0 on a Beaglebone Green.

I am running a build per https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black, built with a Mainline 4.9.30-bone4 (non real time) kernel and the debian-8.7-minimal-armhf-2017-01-14 file system.

The driver was developed and worked on an earlier 3.8 kernel, but now fails to receive any interrupts under the 4.9 kernel.

The interrupt is registered with a call to:

status = request_irq(31, ecap_interrupt, 0, ECAP_NAME, &ecap_data.devid);

31 is the interrupt number for eCAP0INT per table 6.3 in the am335x-techref.

The call succeeds with a zero status, but the interrupt routine is never called even though events are detected by the eCAP unit.
Furthermore, looking at the /proc/interrupts I see:

22:        103      INTC  14 Level     49000000.edma_ccerrint

26:          0      INTC  96 Level     44e07000.gpio

31:          0  44e07000.gpio   4 Edge      ecap

33:          0  44e07000.gpio   6 Edge      48060000.mmc cd

59:          0      INTC  98 Level     4804c000.gpio

92:          0      INTC  32 Level     481ac000.gpio

Which shows that (1) no interrupts have been detected on IRQ 31, and (2) the third column lists a suspicious "44e07000.gpio" instead of INTC as most other interrupt lines do. The latter leads me to believe that the interrupt is not mapped appropriately from the capture unit, but rather to some sort of gpio mapping, although I do not know what the third and the fourth column in /proc/interrupts show.

An attempt to probe for the interrupt using this code also fails with no detected interrupts:

```
do {
    iowrite16(0x0000, &ecap_data.pecap[ECAP_ECEINT]);   // Disable all interrupts
    iowrite16(0x00ff, &ecap_data.pecap[ECAP_ECCLR]);    // And clear status
    mask = probe_irq_on();
    iowrite16(0x0010, &ecap_data.pecap[ECAP_ECEINT]);   // Re-enable CEVT4 interrupt
    iowrite16(0x0010, &ecap_data.pecap[ECAP_ECFRC]);    // And force-trigger it
    udelay(5);
    istatus = probe_irq_off(mask);
    if (istatus == 0) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "No interrupt reported\n");
    }
} while (istatus <= 0 && count++ < 5);
```

It sure looks to me that there is some sort of interrupt mapping/enabling that is new with the 4.x kernels which I am missing.

Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: IIRC, **request_irq()** requires a Linux IRQ number, and not a HW IRQ number, which is what you obtain from the TRM.  The easiest method of getting the Linux IRQ number is to specify the HW IRQ number in the Device Tree.  When the driver's probe routine calls **platform_get_irq()**, the number is already mapped.  You mention absolutely nothing about a Device Tree, which is suspicious for a 4.x ARM kernel build.

Comment: @sawdust: Thanks for your answer, I am starting to get to that realization after beating my head for a few more hours... Perhaps this is against the ethics of this site, but I would love to extend on the subject beyond what is reasonable here, please check my profile.

Comment: Your request is improper.

Comment: I had a somehow similar problem and solved it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628602/unexpected-irq-trap-at-vector-xx-on-beaglebone-black-linux-bbbw-4-14-71-ti-r8/55670072#55670072